# How to run sudo terminal commands with php5?

Tags: php

Under a controlled environment, I will try to execute some calls to shell, some of such commands will include ***`sudo`*** privileges.

I tried this php code line:

```
$out = shell_exec('sudo -u root -S ls < /home/user/.y/.qqz');
```

Where at last `.qqz` is a file containing actual password.

However apache log shows this output:

> *[sudo] password for www-data:*

Like the password file is not being passed to the command stdi?

I already made **`www-data`**  part of the sudo group. How can I get my objective done?

Comment: The point of sudo is to not allow things like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652986/php-sudo-in-shell-exec