# php shell_exec 'reboot' passing sudo password

Tags: php, sudo, shell-exec

This command works :

```
        shell_exec('sudo -u root -S /home/jon/reboot.sh < /home/jon/pwd');
```

The system reboot as expected.

But this fails:

```
        shell_exec('sudo -u root -S /home/jon/reboot.sh < /tmp/Csikea');
```

Why does using a tmp file fail ? it contains the same password as the pwd file.

The apache log shows :  **sudo: pam_authenticate: Conversation error**

I've manually set the owner and permissions on `Csikea` to be the same as `pwd`
Still have the same issue.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652986/php-sudo-in-shell-exec

Comment: Thanks that link gave me this:
`system('echo "PASS" | sudo -u root -S COMMAND');`  which works even better.