# Using sudo command in shell_exec

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

I am trying to use `shell_exec` command in a php file.

`shell_exec(date)` works fine, but `shell_exec(sudo date)` is not working.

Is there any limitation with sudo command in `shell_exec`?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652986/php-sudo-in-shell-exec

Comment: when using sudo in shell_exec, following msg is shown in the brwoser: 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified'

Comment: Don't use `sudo`. Give proper permissions to resources so that the web server can execute the commands without `sudo`

Comment: TTY settings can be altered in sudoers.