# How to execute shell scripts from php that requires root permissions?

Tags: php, shell

Every time I execute my script with:

```
exec('sudo profile status-koneksi',$status);
print_r($status);
```

it always does nothing, I have no idea how to debug this one, my script requires root permission so I appended the following lines to `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
Cmnd_Alias ANGEL_BEATS = /usr/bin/profile, /usr/bin/socks, /usr/bin/gsm, /usr/bin/gssh, /usr/bin/ping_loop, /usr/bin/restart-openvpn, /usr/bin/sms.py, /usr/bin/sms_gateway, /usr/bin/socks, /usr/bin/ussd.py, /usr/bin/vpn, /usr/bin/wgetui
ab ALL=NOPASSWD: ANGEL_BEATS
%ab ALL=NOPASSWD: ANGEL_BEATS
```

However, it works just fine when I execute the command from my terminal:
[image]

How do I solve this ?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by a comment below, I run this script:

```
if(exec("sudo sh /usr/bin/profile status-koneksi 2>&1", $output, $return_var)){ print_r($output); print_r($return_var); }
```

And it returns:

```
Array ( [0] => sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified ) 1
```

Comment: execute like this with error debug mode if(exec(" sh /path/to/file.sh  2>&1", $output, $return_var)){ print_r($output);  print_r($return_var); } and know the error

Comment: Have you tried to add SUID to your script file?

Comment: @KoalaYeung, Sorry I don't understand what you mean, I'm new to linux, how can I do that ?

Comment: This answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/5711685/5788489

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error

Comment: If exec is your answer, you're asking the wrong questions.

Comment: @DarylGill then what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your script requires root permission to run, it would be nice if you could set the `setuid` bit. Try this:

```
chmod u+s <your_script>
```

More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) (from Wikipedia)