# PHP shell_exec to access a system service on deb 9

Tags: php, debian, shell-exec

I'm trying to access a deb system service with PHP `shell_exec` and I just can't get it working.

This is the command I am trying to run from a php script :

```
shell_exec('sudo service icecast2 stop');
```

But it's not working for two reasons..

1) I'm not sure if I'm granting the correct user permissions in `/etc/sudoers` ?

```
%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/???????
```

2) ??????? = I'm not sure where to point to in the /sbin to allow access to system services? I've tried a variety of things but as I'm not sure which part I'm getting wrong (possibly both) I haven't been able to get anything to work.

Any help appreciated ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP sudo in shell\_exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652986/php-sudo-in-shell-exec)

Comment: Does that other question help? There are many others very similar if you search.

Comment: Thanks for posting it but no it doesn't. I must have looked at over 50 different threads (including this one) and articles about this subject but I just can't get this working. Getting no errors in the logs, just not working. Am I even granting the correct user permission? www-data? I'm using Apache2 with nginx reverse proxy if that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Debian systems `service` is in `/usr/sbin`, not in `/sbin`. So it should be:

```
%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

You should also use the full path in the `shell_exec()` command, as `/usr/sbin` might not be in the webserver's `$PATH`.

```
shell_exec('sudo /usr/sbin/service icecast2 stop');
```

Comment: Barmar I could kiss you right now! You have no idea how long I've spent trying to work this out. Thank you so, so much brother :)

Comment: Only have one issue with it.. It only works if I set ALL to root (which is obviously a terrible idea) : `ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service`. When I try to set it to any other user `%www-data` or the actual name my process is running under as reported by using `echo posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'];` it doesn't run. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: I'm not really an expert on configuring `sudo`, [unix.se] would be a better place to ask questions like that.