# Execute Python with PHP receive NULL, how to execute python?

Tags: php, python, null, raspbian

So I've a Raspberry Pi 4, and I've connected a push button to it's GPIO, and the python file is works fine if I execute it from the Terminal.

I get NULL if I execute my Python file from the web site.

So far, I want to achieve that; I want to execute the Python program if I push the button on the webpage, and if I push the button which is connected to the GPIO I want the result on the web page "The time was: %s, when the button was pushed."

Here is the python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import datetime
time=datetime.datetime.now()
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # Import Raspberry Pi GPIO library
def button_callback(channel):
    print("The time was: %s, when the button was pushed." % (time))
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(10,GPIO.RISING,callback=button_callback)
message =raw_input("Press Enter to exit.\n\n")
```

And I have made a PHP file, which looks like this:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <head>
   <title>
     Webpage
   </title>
  </head>

   <form method="post">

    <input type="submit" value="go" name="go">
   </form>
 </body>
</html>

<?php
        if(isset($_POST['go']))
        {
                $output = shell_exec("python sudo /var/www/html/button.py");
                var_dump($output);
        }
?>
```

Thanks for all of the advices.

Comment: Isn't it `sudo python /var/www/html/button.py`? And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652986/php-sudo-in-shell-exec

Comment: Sadly no, I've tried it with, and without sudos, I already tried 
`chmod +x button.py`

Comment: Any error messages in the log files of your webserver?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/button.py", line 10, in <module>
    GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) 
RuntimeError: Not running on a RPi!


This is the only one I can find.